# Condition for Integral of Analytic Function to be Analytic

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $U$ be a complex domain and suppose $f:U \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and, for all $t$, is analytic in $s$.

That is, $f(s, t)$ is continuous and $g_t(s) := f(s, t)$ is analytic for each fixed $t$.

Now define $F(s) := \int_\mathbb{R} f(s, t) \, \text{d}t$.

What conditions do we need on $f$ so that $F$ is analytic on $U$. Specifically,

- If the integral converges for all $s \in U$, is $F$ analytic?
- If not, then what about if the integral converges absolutely for all $s \in U$
- What if the integral converges uniformly?

Basically, what combination of uniform and/or absolute convergence of the integral gives analyticity of $F$?

Comment: If $h_n$ is a sequence of analytic functions converging locally uniformly then the limit is analytic. It is useless to search for an alternative criterion.

Comment: @reuns I'm not aiming for an alternative criterion. With the given setup, I do not have a sequence of analytic functions converging to a limit. If my question can be rephrased in such a way, please elaborate

Comment: Of course you have a sequence..

Comment: @reuns Why are you on the site if your response to questions is being condescending and basically telling people it is obvious. It clearly wasn't obvious to me how your comment applied, so I asked you to elaborate - your response: "of course you have a sequence". Very helpful... The answer may be obvious to you but it obviously wasn't to me; the answer by Robert was actually very helpful compared to your response asserting that the question reduced to something obvious with no effort to actually explain or help me to understand...

Comment: Please don't be insulting. Any Riemann or Lebesgue integral is the limit of a sequence, that's how they are defined.

Comment: @reuns Please don't be condescending... a simple explanation is all that was needed - things may be obvious when pointed out, but responding to questions by explaining that it is clear it clearly rarely helpful (why would anyone ask the question in the first place if it was clear to them). I struggled to understand your original comment and your response was to just assert that it answers the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The basic way we can tell that something is analytic is with Morera's theorem.  What we need to show is that for every
closed piecewise $C^1$ contour (sufficient to be a triangle) $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma$ and its interior are contained in $U$, $$ \int_\Gamma F(s)\; ds = 0$$
We know by Cauchy-Goursat that for every $t$, $\int_\Gamma f(s,t) \; ds = 0$.  So what we want to do is permute the integrals (Fubini's theorem): we want

$$\int_\Gamma \int_{\mathbb R} f(s,t)\; dt \; ds = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_\Gamma f(s,t)\; ds \; dt = 0$$

The basic requirement for this is that the double integral of the absolute value converges:

$$ \int_\Gamma \int_{\mathbb R} |f(s,t)|\; dt \; ds < \infty$$

In particular this is true if  $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(s,t)|\; dt$ is uniformly bounded on every compact set $K \subset U$.