Showing that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ibx}}{\sqrt{\lambda^2 + x^2}}\,dx = 2K_0(\lambda b)$
This is an integral arising from a computation of energy loss during collisions of charged particles in Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics (13.63) in the first edition.
The problem is to show that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ibx}}{\sqrt{\lambda^2 + x^2}}\,dx = 2K_0(\lambda b)$$
Here $K_0$ is the modified Bessel function of order zero. Also $b \gt 0$ is real and $\lambda$ is complex (we can assume it lies in the fourth quadrant, and we choose $\sqrt{\lambda^2 + x^2}$ to also lie in the fourth quadrant). If that helps, we can also assume $\lambda$ is not purely imaginary so that there are no singularities on the integration path.
I already have a proof of the following result for $b \gt 0$:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ibx}}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}\,dx = 2K_0(b)$$
(I used differentiation under the integral sign and the ODE satisfied by the modified Bessel functions).
There is a similar question in Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos{(kx)}}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} \,dx$, but that question was only dealing with the case $a \in \mathbb{R}$ which I have already dealt with.
Ideally, I would simply need to do a substitution $u = \lambda x$ to obtain the general result. This definitely works when $\lambda$ is a positive real number, but if $\lambda$ is complex, the integration path changes to the line spanned by $\lambda$ in the complex plane.

The red lines show the branch cuts for $\sqrt{\lambda^2 + x^2}$ and the original path of integration is $C_1$, $C_4$ (with $R \to \infty$).
I would like to rotate the path of integration to that of $C_2$, $C_5$ using Cauchy's integral theorem (the only singularities are at $\pm i\lambda$ and the branch cuts). The integral along $C_3$ goes to zero as $R \to \infty$ because the integrand is $\frac{e^{ibeR^{i\theta}}}{\sqrt{\lambda^2 + R^2 e^{2i\theta}}} iR$ and $e^{ibeR^{i\theta}} = e^{ibR\cos\theta}e^{-bR\sin\theta}$ quickly approaches zero as $R \to \infty$ for $0 \lt \theta \lt \pi$. But the integral along $C_6$ actually diverges since in that case the exponent has negative imaginary part.
So I am not sure how to continue with this approach.
Another approach would be to use uniqueness of analytic continuations. Since $K_0(\lambda b)$ is analytic for $\Re{\lambda} \gt 0$, it suffices to show that the LHS is also analytic in $\lambda$ in this domain. Knowing that the result holds for $\lambda \gt 0$ will then imply the general result. But due to the presence of the square root, I am not sure how obvious it is that the LHS is analytic in $\lambda$.

@MarkViola That's what I first tried doing, but I did not see a way to avoid dealing with $C_6$ in the image (the integral over $C_6$ is badly-behaved). Maybe there is a better choice of contour, though.

If $\operatorname{Re}(\lambda)>0$ (or more precisely $|\arg\lambda| <\pi/2$), it is clear that $\sqrt{\lambda^2 +x^2}$ is an analytic function of $\lambda$ for any real $x$, since $|\arg(\lambda^2 +x^2)|<\pi$.

@Gary Hmm maybe this was simpler than I thought then. Do we also know that improper integrals of analytic functions are analytic? I wonder if there are some caveats in general.

@TobErnack How are you defining the Modified Bessel Function $K_0(x)$?  Is it one of the soluitons to an ODE?  Does it have an integral representation that you take as a definition and then wish to show that it is equal to the integral $\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{ibx}}{\sqrt{\lambda^2+x^2}},dx$?  What is the starting point?

@MarkViola My starting point is the definition in terms of the regular Bessel functions: $K_\nu(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}i^{\nu+1}(J_\nu(x) + i Y_\nu(x))$. For $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$ my starting point is that they are the solutions to Bessel's ODE with $J_\nu(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $Y_\nu(x) = \frac{J_\nu(x)\cos\nu\pi - J_{-\nu}(x)}{\sin\nu\pi}$ (or the limit as $\nu \to n$ in the integer case). I am willing to take for granted the asymptotics of $J_\nu$ and $Y_\nu$ as $x \to 0$ or $x \to \infty$. I also know the Bessel integrals.

So ideally I would like to see the integral reduced to an integral of Bessel type with imaginary arguments, or to a solution of a modified Bessel ODE, or to the integral I referred to earlier (which you proved in the case $a \in \mathbb{R}$ already). Sorry typo: $K_\nu(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}i^{\nu+1}(J_\nu(ix) + iY_\nu(ix))$.

@TobErnack See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3495225
